# Material table datasource filter with column value having space

Tags: angular, material-design

We do filter on a column having values containing a space like : 'Test 1','Test 12', 'Test 3'

I did a custom predicate like this

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data: any, filterValue: string) {
      return data.UserName /** replace this with the column name you want to filter */
        .replace(/\s/g, "").trim()
        .toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.replace(/\s/g, "").trim().toLocaleLowerCase()) >= 0;
    };
```

Then a function applyFilter:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

I stil encounter problems:
I i search on 'Test 1' I see in the result dataSource Test 2, Test 3, Test 4...

I think i missed something

Thanks for your help

Laurent

Comment: And i do not see console.log inside my filterPredicate. I wonder if the filterPredicate is fired

Answer (score 0):

I think your index search must > 0

`indexOf(...) > 0`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no, same issue

Comment: On Stackblitz I do not have the problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-y1a9ws . And I have the same code in TS file for filtering.

Comment: In the code on my desktop , it doesn't work. I have a log in the customFilterPredicate function but i don't see the trace , whereas I see it on Stackblitz. It seems the function for filterPredicate doesn't fire locally.

Comment: I upgraded to Angular 9 (including angular/material) same release than Stackblitz, same problem

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, was independant of Angular 9 but my fault with asynchron